# Android Fragments Backstack: Is it a stack of Fragments or transactions?

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions, stack, back-stack

From the [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html),

> When you perform such a fragment transaction, you can also add it to a
>   back stack that's managed by the activity—**each back stack entry in the
>   activity is a record of the fragment transaction that occurred**. The
>   back stack allows the user to **reverse a fragment transaction** (navigate
>   backwards), by pressing the Back button.

Is this `Backstack` a `stack` of `fragments` or some sort of `transaction` records?

Because if it is a `stack` of `fragments`, and a `fragment` was removed (which mean popping out of the `backstack` I suppose), how would a back-navigation add back the fragment which was popped out of the `stack`?

Then later in the same document,

> Pop **fragments** off the back stack, with popBackStack() ...

This gives the idea that it is a `stack` of `fragment`s?

**So what does a `Fragment`'s `backstack` `stack` contain, fragments or transaction records?
If the former, then how is a remove transaction reversed on back-navigation?**

Comment: Once a fragment is popped out of the `stack`, it cannot be added back (unless you navigate to it).  A Fragment transaction cannot be reversed, it is final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this Backstack a stack of fragments or some sort of transaction records?

A `stack` of fragments.

> If the former, then how is a remove transaction reversed on back-navigation?

In `Fragment`s, you *can* add the fragments to a `BackStack` (it's not automatically added to the `BackStack` like it happens in the case of an `activity`) - you have the *option* of doing it before removing the `fragment`.

**A `Fragment` is added to the `BackStack` only if you explicitly request that by calling `addToBackStack()` during a transaction which removes the fragment.**

So that way, it will be added to the backstack, and when the user navigates backwards, the last added fragment comes on the top of the backstack.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may just be reading into this too much.

Yes, the `backstack` is a `stack` of fragments. When you start a new activity or commit a fragment transaction, the one you're leaving will by default be added to the stack. In this way, you create a chronological list of the fragments that you've gone through.

What the quote you provided means when it says "each back stack entry in the activity is a record of the fragment transaction that occurred" is that each new fragment was added on a fragment transaction, so you have a stack of previous fragments that is, in a way, a record of what you've gone though.

On back-navigation, a fragment is just popped off of the stack and put back on the screen, in effect letting you move backwards through where you came from.

Comment: Thank you, but suppose the user dismisses a dialog fragment. So what is happening there, is the dialog fragment being popped out of the stack?

Comment: You can read about that here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html Just hit ctrl+f and type "back stack" - I'd explain it but it's easier to read it from the source than to have me paraphrase it.